# According to what, MLB teams advance from regular to playoff

Tags: baseball, mlb, postseason

There are 15 teams in each league in MLB regular season games, and 7 teams in each league in post  season games.

According to what, MLB teams advance from regular to playoff? The number of wins? what if two or more teams get the same number of wins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure where you're getting 7 postseason teams.  I think there's a proposal for it, but wouldn't happen before 2022.

Since 2012, MLB has had 5 teams from each league qualify for postseason play: three division winners and two wild-card teams.

All of these are chosen by a team's win-loss record (with every chance taken to play all games for teams that are in contention).

It is possible for multiple teams to finish the season with identical win-loss records.  If separating them is necessary to determine who will advance, then a single game will be scheduled to break the tie immediately after the end of the regular season.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Major_League_Baseball_tie-breakers#Tie-breakers) has a list of previous tiebreaker games.  Most recently they were played in 2018 when both the NL West and the NL Central had ties for the winner of the division.

If teams are tied, but both would advance and the difference is only to determine home-field, then no tiebreaker game is played.  Instead there are several [rules](https://www.mlb.com/news/playoff-tiebreaker-rules/c-59527184) that are followed, such as head-to-head record, until one team is granted the advantage.